# In codeigniter Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, libraries

```
<?php
 class Token {
 private $CI;

 function __construct($param) {
   $this->CI =& get_instance();
   if($param['flag'] == 1) {
     $this->retrieveToken();
     $this->validateToken();
   }
}

public static function getAuthUserToken($empID) {
   $class = $this->CI->db->query('select * from tbl_emp where emp_id ='.$empID);
   $class = $class->result_array();
   print_r($class);
  }
}
?>
```

I'm creating custom library in codeigniter But, when i try to execute any operation with database.I'm getting above error message

**I also loaded database in autoload.php file**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your static method `getAuthUserToken($empID)` that is causing the error.

As it says in the PHP documentation on the keyword [Static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.methods)

> Because static methods are callable without an instance of the object created, the pseudo-variable $this is not available inside the method declared as static.